# How to denote a simple slope coefficient (interaction)?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

I'm using sslope in stata to test the linear relationship between x and y for different values of my moderator. The output of sslope provides me with a significance level and a coefficient. As far as I know, a simple slope coefficient represents the slope of a regression line for a specific value of my moderator. I report standardized coefficients (betas, "b") in my regular regression table. However, I'm not sure how to report the coefficient provided by sslope. Should i denote this coefficient also "b"?

Comment: What do you mean by "standardized coefficient"?

Comment: betas as provided by the "beta" option in regression in stata.

Comment: You are mixing a lot of notation: simple slope coefficient / interaction / standardized coefficient. Which is it?

Comment: Indeed, I am confused. As far as I know, a simple slope is the slope of a regression line for a specific value of the moderator. The module "sslope" in stata provided me with this slope. My question is, how do I denote this slope/coefficient?

Comment: Can you post your output? Are you just interested in how to write this up in a scientific paper?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what sslope is but it reminds me of linear regression, where we build a model $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$ where:

- $\beta_0$ is a constant.
- $\beta_1$ represents the slope of the line that best fits the data.
- $\epsilon$ is random noise

If this is the case, I would go for $\beta_1$ as the symbol for that coefficient. It there is no intercept (at $X=0$ we have $Y=0$ too) I would go for just $\beta$